# Regular expression with state machine

Tags: c

I am looking for some effective algorithms for regular expression matching.

Something like a function that will have 2 parameters, first , the regular expression, and second the string that need to be matched against this regular expression.

I wrote a simple program that keeps on parsing character by character and take decisions based on *, ?, [] patterns, but I am looking for more simpler and effective solutions.

I thought there must be some sort of state machine for this.

Comment: +1 You're on just the right track -- there's actually pretty deep theory behind it

Comment: could you please refer me to some material where I can look into this deep theory that you are talking about. thanks in advance..

Comment: With respect to Tim Cooper, Don't You Worry Child et al. flagging this as off-topic, this question is a programming- or computer science-related question that has a clear, precise answer.  Please see my response below.

Comment: @Amit The canonical text is "Introduction to Automata Theory Languages and Computation" by Aho, Hopcroft and Ullman.

Comment: Thanks Aaron and Patrick. I have a small question here. I hope am not bothering you guys a lot. If I first convert the regular expression in FA/DFA/NFA and then pass the string to check the matching, wont it be more time consuming? If I simply run a whle loop then I am doing O(n) but in case of FA I will have to first create a FA and then parse?

Comment: @Amit, it looks like maybe you're asking if directly implementing the FA that would parse your regex in the body of a loop would be more efficient than first passing the regex into a converter and then feeding the string to the generated FA.  I would say yes: by implementing the FA by hand, you're essentially doing some work before compile time that might otherwise be done at runtime.

Comment: Aaron thanks for your time and feedback. Exactly this is why I implemented a simple for loop and compared the string with the regex and based on the symbols in regex(?, * etc) parsed the string. But, I got the feedback saying there is a another more simple algorithm for this and then I started my hunt to look for more possible options to solve this. I got that one more possibility is to first generate state machine and then give string to it, but I was feeling that at run time this is more time consuming thought the solution will look elegant.

Comment: Do you think there is some simpler algorithm that I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

There's a direct equivalence between regular expressions and finite automata.  Here's a summary of the regular expression to nondeterministic finite automaton conversion, with performance analysis: http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html.  It also covers converting NFAs to DFAs.

Comment: Thanks Aaron...let me go through this link...